# Scrollbar on x-axis in Time Series Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I would like to create a chart with "Highcharts", in particular use **Time series, zoomable**

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series/dark-green

It is possible to insert a scrollbar to the x-axis?

This jsfiddle of time series chart:

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-time-series/`
```

I tried adding:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>

 scrollbar: {
    enabled: true
 }
```

but doesn't work...

Comment: It works.. http://jsfiddle.net/mkshhg0L/

Comment: you are right, i'm stupid... in jsfiddle i wrote "enable" and not "enabled"... sorry!!! thanks